# Getting cannot find an index in the referenced table error

Tags: mysql, sqlyog

> Cannot find an index in the referenced table where the referenced columns appear as the first columns, or column types in the table and the referenced table do not match for constraint. Note that the internal storage type of ENUM and SET changed in tables created with >= InnoDB-4.1.12, and such columns in old tables cannot be referenced by such columns in new tables.

Above is the full description of error im getting. i checked the indexes of both table and should be fine but it still gives me this error.

Below is the tables structure.

```
CREATE TABLE `contact_address` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `address_type` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `address` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `postcode` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `area` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `state` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `country` char(2) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `fax` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `contact_branch_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `created_by` int(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_by` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_c_a_area` (`area`),
  KEY `fk_c_a_state` (`state`),
  KEY `fk_c_a_country` (`country`),
  KEY `fk_c_a_contact_branch_id` (`contact_branch_id`),
  KEY `fk_c_a_created_by` (`created_by`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_c_a_area` FOREIGN KEY (`area`) REFERENCES `ref_area` (`area_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_c_a_contact_branch_id` FOREIGN KEY (`contact_branch_id`) REFERENCES `contact_branch` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_c_a_created_by` FOREIGN KEY (`created_by`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_c_a_state` FOREIGN KEY (`state`) REFERENCES `ref_state` (`state_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

CREATE TABLE `ref_countries` (
  `country_code` char(2) NOT NULL,
  `country_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `country_name` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  `alpha_3` char(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `calling_code` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `continent_name` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`country_code`),
  KEY `country_id` (`country_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=253 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

Im trying to run this and giving me the error.

```
ALTER TABLE `contact_address`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_c_a_countries` FOREIGN KEY (`country`) 
  REFERENCES `ref_countries` (`country_code`);
```

Comment: try to configure your collation on `country_code` in `ref_countries` table. [the docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) specifically said, *"For nonbinary (character) string columns, the **character set and collation** must be the same."*

Comment: you likely have a collation difference; I'm guessing the collation in ref_countries is utf8mb4_general_ci or utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci, not utf8mb4_unicode_ci.  change one table or the other so they match.  and in general specify collation in addition to charset so you aren't subject to different defaults in different versions

Comment: i didnt went through the code thoroughly, it seems that changing the collation through sqlyog doesnt change the collation of columns in table which is kinda weird imo. Its solved thanks!